# Problem with separating hyperplane statement and notation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem with some [notes](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/SeparatingHyperplane.pdf) I found on separating hyperplane theorems.

Given $\mathbf{p} \in \Re^n$ and $\alpha \in \Re$, here there is some quick notational background that I am adding, because I am not sure of how standard some of this notation is (actually, I am slightly changing it from the notes, by writing vectors in boldface).

- $[ \mathbf{p} \geq \alpha]$ denote the set $\{ \mathbf{x}  \in \Re^n : \mathbf{p} \cdot x \geq \alpha \}$ (changes are inequality-wise);
- $\mathbf{p} \neq \mathbf{0}$, or the hyperplane $[\mathbf{p} = \alpha]$, separates $A$ and $B$ if either $A \subset [\mathbf{p} \geq \alpha]$ and $B \subset [\mathbf{p} \leq \alpha]$, or $B \subset [\mathbf{p} \leq \alpha]$ and $A \subset [\mathbf{p} \geq \alpha]$.

Here there is my problem with the example 1.

$A= \{(\xi,\eta):\eta > \frac{1}{|\xi|} \wedge \xi<0 \}$

$B= \{(\xi, \eta): \eta > \frac{1}{\xi} \wedge \xi>0 \}$

$C = \{(\xi, \eta) : \eta = 0 \}$.

[image]

Then the author states that $\mathbf{p} = (1, 0)$ strictly separates $A$ and $B$, but they cannot be strongly separated.

Now, This should mean that we get a line of the form $\xi = \alpha$, but still this is not enough, right?
The proper statment should be that $[ \mathbf{p} = 0]$ strictly separates $A$ and $B$, where $[ \mathbf{p} = 0]$ means that (in particular) $\mathbf{p} = (1, 0)$ along with $\alpha = 0$ gives the desired result.

I am pretty sure I can't see the forest for the trees and I am making a mountain out of a molehill, but this is very puzzling.

As always, any hint or feedback or help is more than welcome!
Thanks in advance.

PS: I hope the tag is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyperplane
$$
\{ (\xi,\eta)\in\mathbb R^2: \ (\xi,\eta)\cdot (1,0) = 0\}
=\{(0,\alpha)\in\mathbb R^2\}
$$
strictly separates $A$ and $B$. I.e. the line of points of the type $(0,\alpha)$ separates $A$ and $B$.

In the notes it should then read: for $p=(1,0)$ the hyperplane $[p=0]$ separates $A$ and $B$.

Comment: So, basically my interpretation should be right. We can state that $\alpha = 0$, can't we?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that for $\alpha=0$, $p=(1,0)$ the hyperplane $[p=\alpha]$ separates $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Just last question. Is it a minor point not to mention the value of $\alpha$ or it should explicitly stated (even if probably absolutely obvious)? Actually, $[\mathbf{p} = 0 ]$ should be (at least to me) more informative than $\mathbf{p} = (1,0)$.

Comment: Of course, the value of $\alpha$ should be made explicit: either '$[p=0]$' or '$[p=\alpha]$ with $\alpha=0$'.